# How to Install standalone Ubuntu while keeping Windows?

Tags: system-installation, windows, windows-10

I have a laptop with factory installed Windows 10. Since the laptop does not have CD/DVD, Windows can be re-installed from within Windows.

I want to install Ubuntu as a standalone (single) OS on the laptop, but wish to reserve the factory Windows too (not as a working OS, but as a installation medium) to re-install Windows by returning to factory settings.

Is there any way to keep installable windows?

Answer (score 2):

There is a recovery partition for Windows, where are actually stored installation files. You can preserve this partition while installing Ubuntu.